# Android gesture recognition - vertical lines

Tags: android, line, gesture, gesture-recognition

I am creating an android application. In which I am recognizing the Line(Both vertical & horizontal). I have used the following steps.

```
1) Creating straight lines gesture file using "Gestures Builder" application. 
2) Added the "gestures" file in my application and used the "OnGesturePerformedListener" to recognize the line.

The problem is,
I can't recognize the vertical lines(Both Top to Bottom & Bottom to Top).
```

I can recognize the straight lines other than vertical lines. Can anybody know how to get the vertical line detection?

> Code snippet:

```
public class GestureActivity extends Activity implements OnGesturePerformedListener {
    private GestureLibrary mLibrary;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GestureOverlayView gestureOverlayView = new GestureOverlayView(this);
    View inflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_gesture,
            null);
    gestureOverlayView.addView(inflate);
    gestureOverlayView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
    mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
    if (!mLibrary.load()) {
        finish();
    }
    setContentView(gestureOverlayView);
}

@Override
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);
    if (predictions.size() > 0) {
        Prediction prediction = predictions.get(0);
        if (prediction.name.equals("Line") && prediction.score > 1.0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Line", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: post your code here for solution....

Comment: please provide some details.

Comment: @Md Abdul Gafur: Thanks for the response. I have posted my code in the  question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. The answer is given below.

```
gestureOverlayView.setGestureStrokeAngleThreshold( 90.0f);
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22807326/1485254